# how to look up file content in unix bash script

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sh

i have a look up file like below, wants to match the input value against the look up, if its match i need to perform some logic. the look up count was > 200k so the below code tooks long time. please help with AWK

```
cat Lookup.txt
a=10
b=20
c=40



 IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -r -a lines < Lookup.txt 
for u in "${lines[@]}"
do
lookupvalue="$(cut -d'=' f1 <<<$u)"
if[[$1 == *"lookupvalue"*]] then;
 echo "am doing logic here"
else
 echo "not found"
fi

testing : ./test.ksh b
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#! /bin/bash

value="$(awk -F'=' -v key="$1" 'key == $1 {print $2}' Lookup.txt)"
if [ -n "$value" ]
then
    echo "am doing logic here"
else
    echo "not found"
fi
```

Here `$(awk -F'=' -v key="$1" 'key == $1 {print $2}' Lookup.txt)` have the value of the key and null if key doesn't exist. Like if `$1` was `a`, the `awk` expression will result into `10` and the result will be stored in `value`. 
You can use `value` if you wish to.

`-n` checks if the result of `awk` expression is not null. If it is not null then `echo "am doing logic here"`

Answer (score 0):

Guess you are looking up a single key in the file, here is a simple solution:

```sh
$ awk '{split($0, a, "="); if (a[1] == "b") {print(a[1], a[2], "(do some logic)")}}' lookup.txt
b 20 (do some logic)
```

`split($0, a, "=")` splits the line `$0` up by `=` and save to array `a`, so `a[1] == 'b', a[2] == '20'`.